# how to resize image before fetching it?

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, react-native

Say I have an Image Component that has a uri as its source:

```
return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {} } 
         <Image source={{uri: "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/00000000000000000000000000000000?d=mm&f=y"}} />       
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

If it happened that that uri belongs to a very big image, Can I control the size of the image and explicitly set its height and width before fetching it? Or that can't happen from the client side?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know how you can determine the size of the image without making a network request. Does gravatar response to HEAD requests and if it does what does it return?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule not sure about that, but gvatar was just an example. I am wondering if my request is provided by react native (despite what uri I am calling)

Comment: Unless you are controlling the api and returning a resized image according to the url parameters or something, setting the size of the image won't change the size of the request. Yes you can resize it but it would be just a visual resize as it will be resize with css or sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're fetching the image from an API, sometimes you can specify the desired image size in the request.

For example, since in your question you are fetching from a Gravatar API, [you could simply specify the desired image size using the `s` or `size` parameter](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/):

```
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/00000000000000000000000000000000?d=mm&f=y&s=200
```

When you're using an API, check the developer documentation for features like this so that you know what you're working with.